# Swift: Set Insertion Point in NSTextField

Tags: swift, macos, nstextfield

I have a NSTextField with some text "sometext". How can I place the cursor between e and t: "some|text" programmatically?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set your text field current editor selected range property. Try like this:

```
textField.currentEditor()?.selectedRange = NSRange(location: 4, length: 0)
```

You will need to call displayIfNeeded

```
textField.displayIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot. I was desperately lost in the documentation, I think.

Comment: Just leaving this comment for all other beginners (like me) who want the cursor be placed behind the last character: if you want to get the `location` value in `NSRange` from a specific `String` then just calculate the length of it. Example: `let stringLength = yourString.count` If your `String` is - let's say - an `Int` just call it `String(yourInt).count` Then setup your `NSRange` as follows: `textField.currentEditor()?.selectedRange = NSRange(location: stringLength, length: 0)`