# How to find the text insertion point position in an NSTextView in Swift?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstextview

In an NSTextView, I would like to find where the caret, or the start of a selection has been placed as a integer. How could I do that?

I tried with this statement:

```
@IBOutlet var mainTextField: NSTextView!

let theSelectedRange = mainTextField.selectedRange
cursorPosition = mainTextField.offset(from: mainTextField.beginningOfDocument, to: theSelectedRange.start)
```

but I get the error:

> Value of type 'NSTextView' has no member 'offset'

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1701129/how-to-find-caret-position-in-an-nstextview) but I can't translate the solution in Swift due my little experience.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34247107/2303865

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let selectedRange = self.textViewIn.selectedRanges.last
print(selectedRange ?? "No Selected")
```

Output: `NSRange: {0, 3})`

Answer (score 0):

```
let insertionPointIndex = myTextView.selectedRanges.first?.rangeValue.location
```